Every line has a point? and Axiom I.3 of Foundations of Geometry (by Hilbert)
In the book Foundations of Geometry by Hilbert, I can't find an axiom in Axiom Group I (Axioms of Incidence) where it is stated explicitly that a line must have a point. However, part of Axiom I.3 reads "there exist at least two points on a line". I will take this to mean there exist two points in the universe of discourse and, by Axiom I.1, these two points lie on a line. If the statement "every line must have a point" is provable, can you show me a proof of it? Is it also true that every line must have at least two distinct points? It seems to me an easy way to prove Theorem 2 therein is to assume that every line has two distinct points.

Axiom I.3 says that every line has at least two points. So every line must have a point.

Compare with George Birkhoff, A Set of Postulates for Plane Geometry Based on Scale and Protractor (Annals of Mathematics, 1932): "The undefined elements are (a) points, designated by A,B, ... , and (b) certain classes of points called (straight) lines..."

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA I want to prove that any given line has a point in it. Surely, given two distinct points, a unique line is determined (by Axioms I.1 and I.2). But it doesn't say explicitly a line contains a point to begin with.

@lhf Are you sure this is the correct way to interpret the first part of Axiom I.3? I think it means there exist two points and they necessarily lie on a unique line (by Axioms I.1 and I.2). Not that every line has two distinct points.

Maybe a more precise formulation will start with a collection of objects (called points) and a set of subset of the collection (called lines).

"We think of these points, straight lines, and planes as having certain mutual relations,
which we indicate by means of such words as “are situated,” “between,”..." Different terminology is used but the basic fact is taht there ia a relation between point and lines: "belonging to" or "lies on". Thus, Ax.I.3 is: "At least two points lie on any straight line." I.e. $\forall l \exists A, B (A \ne B \land A \in l \land B \in l)$.

And requirements like: (1) Every line has a point. (2) Two lines are the same iff they contain the same points. etc.

@Mauro ALLEGRANZA Thanks for the link! Much needed!

Unfortunately, the formulation "there exist two points on a line" is perhaps ambiguous and sounds like it means $\exists p_1,\exists p_2,\exists \ell\colon p_1\ne p_2\land p_1\in\ell\land p_2\in\ell$ instead of $\forall \ell,\exists p_1,\exists p_2\colon p_1\ne p_2\land p_1\in\ell\land p_2\in\ell$

@Hagen von Eitzen Exactly! I guess in the original German version, Hilbert would have written it in a way that's obvious as to what's actually meant (after all, it was Hilbert's masterpiece on THE foundation of Euclidean Geometry).
